# Bulma align button at the bottom of a column

Tags: css, button, flexbox, vertical-alignment, bulma

So I'm having a hard time aligning a button at the bottom of my Bulma's column.

[image]

I want the button "Buy" to be at the bottom of the right column (side by side with the button "Hello"). I'm in this situation because my other column content is longer.

So far I tried thoses CSS styles on my button (and none of them helped me):

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

---

```
margin-bottom: auto;
```

---

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
        <div class="column is-one-fifth">
            <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a big column</h4>
            I'm taller than the column next to me so my column will be bigger, lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth">Hello</button>
        </div>

        <div class="column is-one-fifth">
            <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a small column</h4>
            I'm a small column, and my button missplaced
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth">BUY</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Could you guys help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, foud the answer : The Bulma column needs to have a few properties (suggested by @ahsan-ullah). Then the button needs to have an auto margin to top.

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
        <div class="column is-one-fifth item">
            <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a big column</h4>
            I'm taller than the column next to me so my button will be higher,lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth">Hello</button>
        </div>

        <div class="column is-one-fifth item">
            <h4 class="title is-4" style="align-self: flex-start;">I'm a small column</h4>
            I'm a small column, and my button is well placed
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth">BUY</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

```
.item{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between
  }

.columns button{
    margin-top: auto;
  }
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: know how to adapt this for the bulma cards?

Comment: I use `.is-flex` for Bulma columns, this allows the column height to be the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43569654/7908914 for details. This works great with both child boxes and cards.

Answer (score 1):

hope it is the answer for you work.

```css
.maindiv{
  width:200px;
  height:180px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between
}

.innerdiv{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

button{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius:4px
}
```

```html
<div class='maindiv'>
  <h3>Mana Foutan</h3>
  <span>lorem ipsum lorem ispum</span>
  
  <div class='innerdiv'>
    <i>Make it rain!</i>
    <button>Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't produce exactly what I want, and Bulma is reacting badly to it, but it will do for the moment. I keep the thread open, in case som Bulma guru could help me a bit more. TY nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Bulma currently supports [flexbox helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/flexbox-helpers/) and [spacing helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/). So just use them here:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
        <div class="column is-one-fifth is-flex is-flex-direction-column">
            <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a big column</h4>
            I'm taller than the column next to me so my button will be higher,lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth mt-auto">Hello</button>
        </div>

        <div class="column is-one-fifth is-flex is-flex-direction-column">
            <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a small column</h4>
            I'm a small column, and my button is well placed
            <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
            <button class="button is-fullwidth mt-auto">BUY</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style `margin-top:auto` on the column div like this:

```
    <div class="column is-one-fifth" style="margin-top: auto;">
        <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a small column</h4>
        I'm a small column, and my button missplaced
        <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
        <button class="button is-fullwidth">BUY</button>
    </div>
```

Alternately, probably preferably, add it as a custom style to your .css and use it as a class inline.

.css:

```
.valignbottom{
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="column is-one-fifth valignbottom">
        <h4 class="title is-4">I'm a small column</h4>
        I'm a small column, and my button missplaced
        <h6 class="sub">"lorem ipsum"</h6>
        <button class="button is-fullwidth">BUY</button>
    </div>
```